# Microsoftgraph sample not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to deploy the Microsoft Graph [snippets sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/) but after publishing to Azure I can login to the app but all the features give me an authorization error.

I can't find how to configure the "Allow Implicit Flow" from the Azure Portal App Registration page. Also, under Required Permissions should I add "Microsoft Graph" "graph" or "graph api"? This is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample application is using the AAD v2 Endpoint. When you register your app via the Azure Portal however, you're registering it under the AAD v1 Endpoint.

You need to register your application using the v2 registration portal at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. This is documented in the [Register the application](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/#register-the-application) section of the readme. You may also want a walkthrough I wrote up this as well: [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configured the Redirect URI correctly.

I can see the URL in example is https://localhost:44300/. As you mentioned that you published the app to Azure, then the URL should be the URL of the hosted application. Only then, the app get authorized to access Graph APIs.